# Finding the most common strings in SQLite

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I want to find the most commonly occurring string from two relations in sqlite. However, I can't use a natural join operator as the strings have the same field name in the schema for two relations I need to operate on.

Let's say I have tables with the following values:

```
X            Y
names       names     
--           --
'a'         'a'
'b'         'c'
'c'         'c'
'c'         'x'
'b'         'z'
```

Since these two tables both have names as a field, I am finding it difficult to find the most frequently occurring string. How should I go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can prefix a field with the table name or you can add an alias to a specific field to disambiguate it -- but I don't think you need to do anything like that to solve this problem.  I would do something like this:

```
SELECT   names,
         count(*)
FROM     (SELECT names FROM x UNION ALL SELECT names FROM y)
GROUP BY names
ORDER BY count(*) DESC;
```

Results

```
names|count(*)
c|4
a|2
b|2
x|1
y|1
```